# How to avoid duplicate value in TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a powerful and easy way to avoid duplicate values in a TreeView, now I perform the insertion in this way:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
     checkExists(rdr.GetString(3));
     rootNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = rdr.GetString(3) });
}
```

where RDR is a player that contains all the values to be added recursively. Now if these values have already been added, I would get duplicate values, so I created a function checkExists you should check if the value is already in the TreeView. I have not found solutions for WPF and I'm still learning how to use this control, I'd know how to do this.

```
public void checkExists(string campionato) 
{
      foreach (TreeView node in nation_team)
      {
           if (NodeExists(node, campionato))
           exists = true;
      }
}
```

This method is not ready, it's just a beta.

```
private bool NodeExists(TreeNode node, string key) {
        foreach (TreeNode subNode in node.Nodes) {
            if (subNode.Text == key) {
                return true;
            }
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0) {
                NodeExists(node, key);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Possible solution that I've tried, in the foreach I'm trying to iterate through the all nodes, but the compiler tell me about GetEnumerator

Comment: so, is the problem with your checkExists method? post the code to that

Comment: oh sorry I missing to paste the method

Comment: post code to NodeExists?

Comment: where do you check the value of exists?

Comment: What I posted is a sample code, I understand how I can do this effectively.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, your `NodeExists` function is not working. You see, you are not doing anything with your second case, and that's why is giving you an error. Also, you need to check the children of `subNode`

A proper solution, would be like this:

```
private bool NodeExists(TreeNode node, string key) 
{
    foreach (TreeNode subNode in node.Nodes) 
    {
        if ( subNode.Text.Equals(key) ) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        var nodeChildExists = NodeExists( subNode.Nodes, key );

        if(nodeChildExists)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This solution is for windows form not for wpf

Comment: @Bender ?? But your question tag says WPF, does it not?

Answer (score 0):

After getting out of almost head to knock this algorithm, as they are new in WPF and in particular I've never worked on TreeView, I did:

```
var newHeader = rdr.GetString(3); //it is a reader that contains the current node, for example "Home"
var exists = false;

foreach (TreeViewItem item in rootNode.Items) //iterate through all nodes
{
         var header = item.Header;

         if (header.Equals(newHeader))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Item already inserted!!");
             exists = true;
             break;
         }
 }

 if (!exists)
 {
       rootNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = newHeader });
 }
```

This works well for me, I'll stay anyway my question open in case someone finds a better solution than mine and more optimized, oh yes .. I'm a maniac optimization. If you could reduce everything to a single line of code, well .. I would.